# Making class constructor private

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, constructor, auto

I am writing a simple garbage collector in C++. I need a singleton class GarbageCollector to deal with different types of memory.
I used a Meyer's singleton pattern. But when I try to call instance, an error appears:

```
 error: ‘GarbageCollector::GarbageCollector(const GarbageCollector&)’ is private
    GarbageCollector(const GarbageCollector&);
    ^
```

Here is the class definition.

```
class GarbageCollector //Meyers singleton (http://cpp-reference.ru/patterns/creational-patterns/singleton/)
{
 public:
    static GarbageCollector& instance(){
        static GarbageCollector gc; 
        return gc; 
    }   
    size_t allocated_heap_memory;
    size_t max_heap_memory;
private:
    //Copying, = and new are not available to be used by user.
    GarbageCollector(){};
    GarbageCollector(const GarbageCollector&);
    GarbageCollector& operator=(GarbageCollector&);
};
```

I call the instance with the following line:
`auto gc = GarbageCollector::instance();`

Comment: In your `class` there is a comment: `Copying,[...] are not available [...]`. You are getting the error because you are copying the gc

Comment: Everything is said in the error message `GarbageCollector(const GarbageCollector&);` is private. You cannot call a private constructor from outside the class.

Comment: @Elyasin: Not everything.  The surprising bit is that the `auto` variable is declared as a `GarbageCollector`, not `GarbageCollector&`.

Comment: Given you are using `auto`, you might as well delete the copy constructor and assignment, rather than just declaring them private - then you can't copy even *inside* the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
auto gc = GarbageCollector::instance();
```

to

```
auto& gc = GarbageCollector::instance();
```

Otherwise `gc` is not a reference, then returned `GarbageCollector` need to be copied, but the copy ctor is private, that's why compiler complains.